# k-NN Algorithm with own distance function from scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to use the k-NN Algorithm from scikit-learn.
For the distance function, I want to use my "own" function. These should be calculated by the tanimoto coefficient.

I wrote the tanimo function and give it to the metric parameter in scikit learn.

My data is containing only 1's and 0's (so all features are only 1 or 0).

For the tanimo, im calculation all 1's in x and y and return a skalar= the coefficient.
The KNN function is called like this: `KNeighborsClassifier(metric=tanimoto).fit(X_train,y_train)`

```
def tanimoto(x,y):
    print x
    print y
    a=x.tolist()
    b=y.tolist()


    c=np.count_nonzero(x==y)
    a1=a.count(1.0)
    b1=b.count(1.0)

    return float(c)/(a1 + b1 - c)
```

If I'm printing x and y, they should be actually only 1's and 0's or not?

The output from print x, y in tanimoto is:

```
X:
[ 0.6371319   0.54557285  0.30214217  0.14690307  0.49778446  0.89183238
  0.52445514  0.63379164  0.71873681  0.55008567]

Y:
[ 0.6371319   0.54557285  0.30214217  0.14690307  0.49778446  0.89183238
  0.52445514  0.63379164  0.71873681  0.55008567]

X:
[ 0.          0.          0.          0.02358491  0.00471698  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.00471698  0.00471698  0.00471698  0.02830189
  0.00943396  0.     .............................52358491  0.53773585
  0.63207547  0.51886792  0.66037736  0.75        0.57075472  0.59433962
  0.63679245  0.8490566   0.71698113  0.02358491]

Y:
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.
  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.] 

  # and so on ... X is always a skalar vector and y the vector how it should be. (only 1 and 0)
```

my X_train vector:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  1.  1.  0.]
 ...,
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

here is the Code-example

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors  


def tanimoto(x,b):

    print "X  OUTPUT\n  ",x,"B OUTPUT\n",b

    c=np.sum(x==b)
    a1 = np.sum(x)
    b1 = np.sum(b)

    if (a1 + b1 - c)==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return float(c)/(a1 + b1 - c)

tests=[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]

classifiers=NearestNeighbors( n_neighbors=4,algorithm='ball_tree',metric=tanimoto).fit(tests)


#example
```

and the whole output, if I'm printing out x,b in the tanimoto function

```
------------ new Fingerprint ------------
fingerprint:  macc
-----------------------------------------
X  OUTPUT
   [ 0.86899132  0.85534082  0.21453329  0.24435568  0.32321695  0.6926369
  0.5124301   0.98725159  0.01685611  0.58985301] B OUTPUT
[ 0.86899132  0.85534082  0.21453329  0.24435568  0.32321695  0.6926369
  0.5124301   0.98725159  0.01685611  0.58985301]
X  OUTPUT
   [ 0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909
  0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.
  0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.
  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.09090909  0.18181818
  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909
  0.          0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.          0.09090909  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.18181818
  0.09090909  0.18181818  0.          0.          0.27272727  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.27272727  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.18181818  0.          0.36363636  0.          0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.27272727  0.27272727  0.18181818  0.          0.09090909
  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.18181818  0.27272727  0.45454545  0.18181818
  0.27272727  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.45454545
  0.          0.36363636  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.36363636
  0.54545455  0.          0.54545455  0.36363636  0.45454545  0.27272727
  0.09090909  0.54545455  0.18181818  0.09090909  0.27272727  0.45454545
  0.27272727  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.36363636  0.54545455  0.54545455
  0.09090909  0.18181818  0.27272727  0.18181818  0.36363636  0.
  0.54545455  0.          0.45454545  0.54545455  0.18181818  0.18181818
  0.18181818  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.54545455  0.45454545  0.36363636
  0.54545455  0.18181818  0.45454545  0.54545455  0.54545455  0.18181818
  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.63636364  0.54545455  0.54545455  0.63636364
  0.45454545  0.72727273  0.63636364  0.54545455  0.54545455  0.63636364
  0.90909091  0.63636364  0.18181818] B OUTPUT
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.
  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.
  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
X  OUTPUT
   [ 0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909
  0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.
  0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.
  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.09090909  0.18181818
  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909
  0.          0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.          0.09090909  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.18181818
  0.09090909  0.18181818  0.          0.          0.27272727  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.27272727  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.18181818  0.          0.36363636  0.          0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.27272727  0.27272727  0.18181818  0.          0.09090909
  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.18181818  0.27272727  0.45454545  0.18181818
  0.27272727  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.45454545
  0.          0.36363636  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.36363636
  0.54545455  0.          0.54545455  0.36363636  0.45454545  0.27272727
  0.09090909  0.54545455  0.18181818  0.09090909  0.27272727  0.45454545
  0.27272727  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.36363636  0.54545455  0.54545455
  0.09090909  0.18181818  0.27272727  0.18181818  0.36363636  0.
  0.54545455  0.          0.45454545  0.54545455  0.18181818  0.18181818
  0.18181818  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.54545455  0.45454545  0.36363636
  0.54545455  0.18181818  0.45454545  0.54545455  0.54545455  0.18181818
  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.63636364  0.54545455  0.54545455  0.63636364
  0.45454545  0.72727273  0.63636364  0.54545455  0.54545455  0.63636364
  0.90909091  0.63636364  0.18181818] B OUTPUT
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
X  OUTPUT
   [ 0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909
  0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.
  0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.
  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.09090909  0.18181818
  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909
  0.          0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.          0.09090909  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.18181818
  0.09090909  0.18181818  0.          0.          0.27272727  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.27272727  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.18181818  0.          0.36363636  0.          0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.27272727  0.27272727  0.18181818  0.          0.09090909
  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.18181818  0.27272727  0.45454545  0.18181818
  0.27272727  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.45454545
  0.          0.36363636  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.36363636
  0.54545455  0.          0.54545455  0.36363636  0.45454545  0.27272727
  0.09090909  0.54545455  0.18181818  0.09090909  0.27272727  0.45454545
  0.27272727  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.36363636  0.54545455  0.54545455
  0.09090909  0.18181818  0.27272727  0.18181818  0.36363636  0.
  0.54545455  0.          0.45454545  0.54545455  0.18181818  0.18181818
  0.18181818  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.54545455  0.45454545  0.36363636
  0.54545455  0.18181818  0.45454545  0.54545455  0.54545455  0.18181818
  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.63636364  0.54545455  0.54545455  0.63636364
  0.45454545  0.72727273  0.63636364  0.54545455  0.54545455  0.63636364
  0.90909091  0.63636364  0.18181818] B OUTPUT
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.
  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.
  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
X  OUTPUT
   [ 0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909
  0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.
  0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.
  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.09090909  0.18181818
  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909
  0.          0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.          0.09090909  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.18181818
  0.09090909  0.18181818  0.          0.          0.27272727  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.27272727  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.18181818  0.          0.36363636  0.          0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.27272727  0.27272727  0.18181818  0.          0.09090909
  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.18181818  0.27272727  0.45454545  0.18181818
  0.27272727  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.45454545
  0.          0.36363636  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.36363636
  0.54545455  0.          0.54545455  0.36363636  0.45454545  0.27272727
  0.09090909  0.54545455  0.18181818  0.09090909  0.27272727  0.45454545
  0.27272727  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.36363636  0.54545455  0.54545455
  0.09090909  0.18181818  0.27272727  0.18181818  0.36363636  0.
  0.54545455  0.          0.45454545  0.54545455  0.18181818  0.18181818
  0.18181818  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.54545455  0.45454545  0.36363636
  0.54545455  0.18181818  0.45454545  0.54545455  0.54545455  0.18181818
  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.63636364  0.54545455  0.54545455  0.63636364
  0.45454545  0.72727273  0.63636364  0.54545455  0.54545455  0.63636364
  0.90909091  0.63636364  0.18181818] B OUTPUT
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.
  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
X  OUTPUT
   [ 0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909
  0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.
  0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.
  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.          0.          0.          0.09090909  0.09090909  0.18181818
  0.          0.          0.09090909  0.          0.          0.09090909
  0.          0.09090909  0.09090909  0.          0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.          0.09090909  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.18181818
  0.09090909  0.18181818  0.          0.          0.27272727  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.27272727  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.18181818  0.          0.36363636  0.          0.09090909
  0.09090909  0.27272727  0.27272727  0.18181818  0.          0.09090909
  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.18181818  0.27272727  0.45454545  0.18181818
  0.27272727  0.09090909  0.09090909  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.45454545
  0.          0.36363636  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.36363636
  0.54545455  0.          0.54545455  0.36363636  0.45454545  0.27272727
  0.09090909  0.54545455  0.18181818  0.09090909  0.27272727  0.45454545
  0.27272727  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.36363636  0.54545455  0.54545455
  0.09090909  0.18181818  0.27272727  0.18181818  0.36363636  0.
  0.54545455  0.          0.45454545  0.54545455  0.18181818  0.18181818
  0.18181818  0.36363636  0.18181818  0.54545455  0.45454545  0.36363636
  0.54545455  0.18181818  0.45454545  0.54545455  0.54545455  0.18181818
  0.45454545  0.45454545  0.63636364  0.54545455  0.54545455  0.63636364
  0.45454545  0.72727273  0.63636364  0.54545455  0.54545455  0.63636364
  0.90909091  0.63636364  0.18181818] B OUTPUT
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.
  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
```

in This data, I'm just using 11 samples

I just copy pasted the test vector from my sample and attribute extraction, but im getting with these, the same problem. Problem= X and B arent 1 and 0, X should also be containing only 1's and 0's

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example with sample data demonstrating the problem?

Comment: please provide the exact code and output - so there is 100% where each output comes from.

Comment: I added the Code example and output. Actually X should look like B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a ball tree.  As described in [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#ball-tree):

> A ball tree recursively divides the data into nodes defined by a centroid C and radius r [...] With this setup, a single distance calculation between a test point and the centroid is sufficient to determine a lower and upper bound on the distance to all points within the node.

In other words, the ball tree doesn't just calculate distances between your points, it often calculates distances between a point and the centroid of some set of points.  Although all your points have coordinates 0 or 1, the centroid of some set of them often will not.